# Square a number using only addition / recursion C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a small recursive function to take in an integer and return the square of that integer only using addition. The formula I found is this: If the user enters 5, the function will take 5 + (4+3+2+1) + (4+3+2+1) = 25. If the user enters 6, the function will take 6 + (5+4+3+2+1) + (5+4+3+2+1) = 36 and so on. The recursive function needs to decrease the value of the integer by 1 every time, and keep adding it to the original number and calling itself until it reaches 0. I am confused on how to write this is C++ and could use some help. Here is my attempt (I know it is completely wrong, but any help is appreciated)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int square (int n){
    int newInt = n;
    newInt = newInt -1;
    n = n + newInt;
    newInt--;
    int square(int n);
}

int main() {
    int n;
    cout<<"Enter a number to square: ";
    cin>>n;
    square(n);
}
```

Comment: `int square(int n);` is another function declaration, not a function call.

Comment: Oh yea so it would be something like square(n) at the end instead of what i wrote.

Comment: Also your function should return a value.

Comment: Remember to return the value of the recursive call to square(). Also, why not just use simple multiplication? The one-liner `return n*n` is faster than recursively adding the numbers.

Comment: Multiplication would be way more practical, but this is a question on our homework and we're learning recursion, so we cannot use * for this.

Comment: Build a multiplication routine first. Use that to create a squaring routine. If they really want you to use a single function, combine them.

Comment: The idea of recursion is that the function takes in a value, modifies the value in some way, then calls itself using the new value. The value it returns is "accumulated". It also has to have a "base case" or a "stop case".  Think of it like climbing down a ladder, marking each step with the formula, hitting the bottom, then climbing back up.  you are going down the ladder one number at a time until you hit the smallest number (the bottom).  Then you climb back up, and do the formula each time as you go, and have a complete value at the top.

Comment: It looks like you haven't quite got the hang of non-recursive functions yet (including how to call a function or return a value), so you might want to focus on that first.

Answer (score 1):

In the listing below

```
int square (int n){
int newInt = n;
newInt = newInt -1;
n = n + newInt;
newInt--;

//and why do you write int?
int square(int n);
}
```

The return value of function square() is not stored anywhere. And in fact your function returns nothing, since there is no return statement.

When you design a recursive function, first thing you should think about is when recursion ends. Your function has no return without recursion condition. That means, that when it reaches 0 it calls square(-1) and so on.

Your code displays nothing as well.

But one big problem - you use function arguments in a very strange way. When a function receives an argument, it is copied, and a clone of the original variable is stored in something called "stack", and addressed with use of a special computer register called RBP (Base Pointer). So, if you have a variable x, and it is passed as an argument to some function, if this function changes it's argument, x still has the same value. So, when you try to change n, it won't work. To override this issue either use pointers or make your function return new value you want to assign n.

Working example:

```
int square(int n)
{
if ( n==0 )
    return 0;
n = square(n-1) + n + n - 1;
return n;
}
```

Comment: You may try to learn some c before going for c++.

Comment: I don't see how learning C will make things better.

Comment: Since you are not fluent with functions and pointers, understanding these in c would help

Comment: I must agree with @MintLover , by the way, a brilliant solution to OP`s problem.